# Trouble connecting to MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php

I have a 3 file:

```
class.database.php
config.php
test.php
```

In class.database.php i using:

```
<?php
class Database {

    private $db_connect;
    function __construct($config) {
        $this->connect($config);
    }

    function connect($config) {
        $this->db_connect = @mysql_connect($config['hostname'], $config['dbuser'], $config['dbpass']) or die("Can't connect to mysql server");
        @mysql_select_db($config['dbname'], $this->db_connect) or die("Can't select database mysql server");
        $this->query('set names utf8'); 
    }

    function disconnect() {
        mysql_close($this->db_connect);
    }

}
?>
```

in config.php i using:

```
<?php
include_once 'class.database.php'; 

$config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['dbuser'] = 'root';
$config['dbpass'] = '';
$config['dbname'] = 'test';

$db = new Database($config); 
?>
```

And test.php i using:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'class.database.php';
```

when to run test.php in wampserver is host alert error is `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Database in class.database.php on line 2`

How to fix it ?

Comment: how did you come up with the name "3 file" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're `include`ing the `class.database.php` file twice, which gives this error. Use `include_once` for it always, not `include`.